# When to split a large table (disk size, #cols) into smaller tables to improve performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, schema, innodb

Got a 14GB myISAM with ~15 rows, soon to be innodb table. The way it is read / written too is fairly compartmentalized. It basically started as a 'shotgun' table to handle a ton of data. In due diligence, I am finding the table is divided into 2-3 basic segments of fields where one of these theoretical segments are being used by the bulk of our applications queries, another segment of the table/fields for other queries etc. Ea. scenario has the appropriate indexing of course.

Is it a simple chore, or more to the point, best practice to say split this one large table up into 3 tables that with a reduced table size/solid index may improve performance? Particularly factoring in perhaps joining 1 or 2 of these in edge cases.

Curious for any input/strategies for approaching this and of course will it really help?

Thanks,

C

Comment: A nice answer is given for your question on 
 http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/how-does-table-partitioning-help

Comment: @PankajKhairnar +1 thank you - I did not come across that in my initial 15 mins or so searching. That is a quite elegant and simple article. I will be sure to up-rate it so that it hopefully will be more prominent on the 'Similar questions to yours' should someone follow in my footsteps. Best Regards.

Comment: @PankajKhairnar - Also was unaware of the new DBA division of the exchange family. I shall keep my dbms questions contained to there now. +1 again for double education.